# What is the canonical way to create tabs to a control panel configlet?

Tags: tabs, plone, controlpanel

Today we use a "Multiple registry schema proxy" class to achieve this, but we think there should be a better way to work with tabs at Plone:

https://github.com/collective/collective.nitf/blob/1.x/src/collective/nitf/controlpanel.py#L163-L202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the easiest way to create a configlet with tabs is using [plone.supermodel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.supermodel):

```py
from my.package import MessageFactory as _
from plone.supermodel import model
from zope import schema

class IMyConfigletSettings(model.Schema):

    """Schema for the control panel form."""

    field_one = schema.Text(
        title=_(u'Field One'),
        default='',
    )

    model.fieldset('tab_a', label=_(u'Tab A'), fields=['field_a'])

    field_a = schema.Text(
        title=_(u'Field A'),
        default='',
    )

    model.fieldset('tab_b', label=_(u'Tab B'), fields=['field_b'])

    field_b = schema.Text(
        title=_(u'Field B'),
        default='',
    )
```

This will create a configlet with 3 fields and 3 tabs (one field per tab).

Take a look at the sc.social.like package for [a working, real-world example](https://github.com/collective/sc.social.like/blob/master/sc/social/like/interfaces.py#L56-L171).

Maybe this can be considered the canonical way from now on.